# Tinymce buttons are not appearing in some pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

Im using the plugin tinymce with image upload and its working fine in a page.

But on other page there is a sidebar at left and the content area is at right. The tinymce plugin is in the content area at right, and in this page the tinymce buttons dont appear, they only appear if the browser is resized to medium devices where the sidebar is hidden and so the tinymce textarea occupies all with and the buttons appear.

Do you know what can be the issue?

I have a example with the issue: "jsfiddle.net/7b941us0/34".

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have a example with the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/7b941us0/34/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank you for providing JSFriddle with an example or your problem.

Your issue is caused by below lines of code (LOC 1378 - 1380) -- removing them fixes the issue.

You literally force all buttons in `.adminContainer` not to be displayed. Removing these lines makes everything work just fine.

```
.adminContainer button {
  display: none;
}
```

Reason why buttons show up for smaller parent's width is because on breakpoint you force these buttons to reappear:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .adminContainer button {
    display: block;
  }
  (...)
```

I suggest you to target exact buttons which you want not to be displayed by adding certain CSS classes.

[Link to working JSFriddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/se5y0g2d/)